# How to do angular validation on html file not on angular controller for specific field based on specific button click

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, validation

Here I am having simple html angular form. I have three fields: Username, address and email.

I have added angular required attribute validations. This works well as expected.

But I have a requirement where when I hit Save I should only validate username and address but not email. And when I hit Submit I should validate only email.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>  
    <title>Form Demo</title>  
    <style>body{font-family:"Arial";background-color:#E2E2DC}</style>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="AppController as ctrl">

      <form name="loginform" >
          UserName<input type="text"  ng-model="ctrl.user.username" placeholder="Enter your name" required/><br/><br/>
          Address<input type="text"  ng-model="ctrl.user.address" placeholder="Enter your Address" required/><br/><br/>
          Email<input type="text"  ng-model="ctrl.user.email" placeholder="Enter your Email" required/><br/><br/>

           <button ng-click='ctrl.submit()'>Save</button>
           <button ng-click='ctrl.submit()'>Submit</button>
      </form>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js">
      </script>  
      <script>
          angular.module('myApp', [])
          .controller('AppController', [function() {
              var self = this;
              self.submit = function() {
                  console.log('Form is submitted with following user', self.user);
            };
      }]);
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could tweak your form based on what button you click make field `required` & optional on demand using `ng-required` directive

```
<form name="loginform" novalidate ng-submit="ctrl.submit(loginform)">
  UserName
  <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="ctrl.user.username" placeholder="Enter your name" ng-required="save"/>
  <br/>
  <br/> Address
  <input type="text" name="address" ng-model="ctrl.user.address" placeholder="Enter your Address" ng-required="save"/>
  <br/>
  <br/> Email
  <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="ctrl.user.email" ng-required="submit" placeholder="Enter your Email"/>
  <br/>
  <button ng-click="save=true;submit=false;">Save</button>
  <button ng-click="submit=true;save=false;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

[**Demo Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/4FclFCK9KOYsYiCxRXk2?p=preview)

Comment: @sgl what do you mean by validation didn't work.. what you have checked??

Comment: Great This works well. Is there any other way instead of using true false flag

Comment: @sgl I made in that way because you want conditional `required` field.. otherwise you have to explicitly check each field inside your submit method. I don't think so it is good. Rather leverage feature provided by angular and have it more declarative way..

Comment: Great Make sense! Thank You!